# Open a complete portable chrome like regular Chrome

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I want to research on how to open a Chrome portable profile so that I can do normal operations without restrictions.

I have done the code to open the chrome profile, but it says "not secure" error and can't login gmail, twitter or facebook.

[image: Not secure and can't login Gmail]

There is another way is to use virtual port and cmd like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVumnHy5Tzo&ab_channel=HelloWorld, the error will be fixed.

But if you do this, then you have to turn on virtual Chrome first, after turning off Chrome with this virtual port, the code can't work anymore (ie can only be used once :xd )

Below is the code that I used to open chrome profile (but can't login to social network)

```
def get_chromedriver(use_proxy=False, Profile = ""):
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={Profile}")
    if use_proxy:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(os.path.join(path, 'chromedriver.exe')),
                                  options=chrome_options)

    return driver

profile1 = get_chromedriver(use_proxy=True, Profile="F:\\Multichorme\\haitacbien199 - Copy\\Data\\profile")
```

I would like to ask is there any other way to be able to open a complete Chrome and be able to login to social media accounts. Thank you for reading and hope you can save my day =))

Answer (score 0):

I've been researching for a few days until now about Selenium, Webbrowser as well as web python related libraries like Request but still haven't fixed the problem.

This is my passing assignment in school, if I don't complete it, I have to retake it. And it will cost a lot of money :zzz. And I don't really want that

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).