# New error discovered when using Chromedriver Selenium

Tags: selenium

When I try to open Chrome with selenium with webdriver, it shows a chrome that looks like this.
[image: Error black screen]

Even though it's been a long wait, it's still the same. While I open it by right clicking, it works fine.

I've tried using all versions of Chromedriver 100 and 99, but the results haven't changed much.
[image: All_Chromedriver]
[image: I_downloaded_this]

Here is the source code that I use:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir=G:\\Multi_Chrome\\testing\\Data\\profile")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service("D:\\Python\\Project\\chromedriver.exe"),
                          options=chrome_options)

input("Press any key to coutinue ...")
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Any ideas? By the way, I want to ask more, how to open a normal portable chrome. Instead of right clicking and choosing open. Is there a way to automatically open it?

I have partially mentioned it in this article: [Open a complete portable chrome like regular Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71514188/open-a-complete-portable-chrome-like-regular-chrome)

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: What is your chrome version?

Comment: I think it might be because my Chrome has updated to 99.0.4844.82, while the latest Chrome Driver version is currently only 99.0.4844.51. 82 is different from 51. Therefore, it is not compatible so it cannot be run

Comment: I think it will take some time for Chromedriver devs to update to version 99.0.4844.82. In the meantime I will try to find a way to automatically open a Chrome Portable as usual. This seems difficult

Answer (score 0):

your question isn't clear because you didn't mention what is the error, but as I see in the screenshot you have already opened one chrome browser before you run the script, but you use `--user-data-dir=G:\\Multi_Chrome\\testing\\Data\\profile` it means that this profile is already is in use so you cant open another chrome browser with the same profile. so The simplest and easiest fix is to close all running chrome browsers and after that try to run your script again

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried closing them all, but it still shows black-white chrome like the screenshot

Comment: @NguyễnCôngLậpNhân maybe you need to upgrade your GPU driver.